# Dirac-delta in real exponential form?

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta, inverse-laplace

While I was studying about the spin-glass model based on replica theory (Spin-glass theory for pedestrians, page 16, equation 49), I have encountered something like an exponential form of Dirac-delta function:
\begin{equation}
\delta(q - \hat{q}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp((q-\hat{q})\lambda)d\lambda
\end{equation}
where both $q$ and $\hat{q}$ are real numbers and $\lambda$ as well. According to this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353118/how-to-express-dirac-delta-function-in-functional-form?rq=1), the quantity $\lambda$ is also called as a Lagrange multiplier. I guess the above form of the equation is somewhat connected to an idea of analytic continuation of complex representation of Dirac-delta. The usual complex form Dirac-delta function looks like following.
\begin{equation}
\delta(q - \hat{q}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp(i\lambda(q-\hat{q}))d\lambda
\end{equation}
Anyways, I have tried to obtain the real exponential form of Dirac-delta function using the Laplace transform and the inverse Laplace transform.
\begin{align}
F(\hat{s}) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\exp(-\hat{s}t)dt \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left[\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{i\infty}^{i\infty}F(s)\exp(st)ds\right]\exp(-\hat{s}t)dt \\
&= \int_{i\infty}^{i\infty}F(s)\left[\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp((s-\hat{s})t)dt\right] ds
\end{align}
I just found the general form of the inverse Laplace transform from google. Then by definition of Dirac-delta function, I obtain the following.
\begin{equation}
\delta(s-\hat{s}) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp((s-\hat{s})t)dt
\end{equation}

It looks similar to the first equation, but there exists a complex constant term and both $s$ and $\hat{s}$ are still complex numbers. What do you think? Can you help me to understand the real exponential form of Dirac-delta function?

Comment: Wasn't there an imaginary number in the exponential?
$$2\pi\,\delta(q - \hat{q}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp(i(q-\hat{q})r)dr$$

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, that is a typical complex form of Dirac-delta function. But it seems like $i$ can be removed under some condition, I guess. While I was studying about the SK spin-glass model, the imaginary number wasn't involved.

Comment: Was the integral then really over all of $\mathbb{R}$ and not just over $(-\infty, 0)$? I've never seen it that way, and I have no clue how to handle positive the infinities arising for $q>\hat{q}$.

Comment: For the first equation? Yes, I think the integration limit is from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Or are you talking about the Laplace transform? I guess it would be alright to express as bilateral Laplace transform... I am not sure.

Comment: I think it is possible that they are implicitely defining the variable as complex. Btw I had the same doubt studying the same notes. Look also at eq. (122) of
https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/madvani/files/repcavmes6.pdf

I think (not an expert AT ALL) that in stat physics they use the hat to indicate complex variable/fields...